# Is my html wrong? or how to check if images are on Heroku?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm using a Rails blogging gem Enki on Heroku, but am having trouble posting images. Out of the box it doesn't come with a way to insert images to pages or posts.  I created a page and put different paths to the image (it's a rails 3.0.4) but the image isn't showing up on the page.

```
<img src="http://blooming-sunrise-4472.heroku.com/public/images/rails.png" alt="Rails" width="50" height="50" />


<img src="public/images/rails.png" alt="Rails" width="50" height="50" />
```

I know the Rails.png is on github but I'm wondering if it's actually on the Heroku site, or is there a problem with how I'm trying to access it?

I logged into my Heroku account, but I can't see anywhere that let's you know what is on their servers.

Can anyone suggest anything?

The url is [My Heroku App](http://blooming-sunrise-4472.heroku.com/) If you click on "image-test" under the pages heading, you will see the page where the images are supposed to be displayed?

Note, having done Michael Hartl's RailsTutorial.org, I know that images can be moved from Github to Heroku, even though I've read SO questions that say can't store on Heroku servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple error,

files in the `/public` directory are treated as the `DocumentRoot` of your application.

So you should refer to "images/rails.png", not "public/images/rails.png"

as such, replace your `<img>` tag with

```
<img src="/images/rails.png" alt="Rails" width="50" height="50" />
```